# content script is not showing up in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, angular5

I have this setting in my manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
```

here is the code in the content-script.js file:

```
console.log('this is the content script.');

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  console.log('the following tab was clicked:', tab);

  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

if I click on the popup button and open the Chrome extension, and click "inspect" and open Dev Tools, I don't see any content scripts listed:

[image]

However, now it gets really weird, because Chrome says that it can't find the manifest.json file:

[image]

However, it's clear that it could find my background.js script, which is declared in my manifest.json file:

[image]

As you can see, the options page, and background page are recognized. So it seems like Chrome does recognize/detect the manifest file.

**Anybody have an idea of what might be wrong? How can I get my content-scripts to be loaded?**

Comment: Also, I tried using this instead `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`, no change in result.

Comment: Make sure to read the [extensions architecture article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). Content scripts run "alongside" web pages - similar to the page's own scripts, but in "isolated world".

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why it says the manifest is not showing up. But I realized you are not supposed to inspect the Extension window to find your content script(s). Instead, open a different tab that uses http and loads a webpage, like http://www.quora.com, and then open Dev Tools and your content script should be loaded there.

Comment: What he said, your extension is based around opening another website and pressing it. You shouldn't be opening the extension itself and inspecting it, most importantly because it's not served over https, which you specified is a requirement for it to be run.

Comment: yeah, even when I changed it to `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`  I still had to navigate to a webpage to load the content scripts

Comment: content_scripts are only used for other websites. Opening your extension itself will never load the content_scripts. What you're looking for in that case is the "background" entry, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts

Comment: content_scripts = other websites, background = your own extension.